# How to run an RFC Function Module in a SAP background job without a predefined login/trusted relationship in SM59?

Tags: abap, background-process, saprfc

I need to run an RFC Function Module inside Report in Background Job. The background job was canceled because of the sap logon screen.

The RFC Destination was maintained in SM59 with ***No Trusted Relationship*** and ***no password provided*** for the Logon Procedure.

Is it possible to do steps like this?

1. Run an RFC Function Module to trigger SAP Logon Screen
2. After the user successfully login to the destination, store the login information
3. Run a report in a background job. By giving the stored login information to the report, expected that it will use the stored login information for running another RFC Function module

Comment: No, anything running inside a background job cannot be connected to a user's laptop, nothing can be displayed on the user's screen. That's what SM59 trusted relationship/password is for in SM59.